# ERD or MCD one-to-many diagrams

Tags: entity-relationship, database-diagram

What is the difference of those two diagrams?

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first diagram is in Chen notation the second diagram is in Crow's foot notation.[image: Different Notations]

Image Source: Wikipedia